# В каких случаях Python создает новый объект?

Tags: python

Если переменная в питон ссылается на неизменяемый тип данных, то создавая вторую переменную, она должна ссылаться на тот же объект. Например `a = 1` и `b = 1`. Условие a is b вернет True.
Но я заметил странную особенность этого правила. 
Если, например, написать `a = '1'` и `b = '1'`, то a is b вернет True, так как они ссылаются на один и тот же объект в памяти.
Но почему тогда при `a = '1 1'` и `b = '1 1'` выражение a is b вернет False? В первом и втором случае тип данных - str, но если добавить пробел, либо написать слово на кириллице, то Python создает уже новый объект. Как это объяснить?

Comment: для не изменяемых объектов можно условно считать что всегда создаётся новый. Для изменяемых меняется только содержимое объекта, сам объект контейнер не меняется.

Comment: Не воспроизводится. При а и б "1 1" (или любая другая строка) a is b возвращает тру.

Comment: А вы точно писали a = '1 1' как str?

Comment: А как можно иначе написать "1 1"? Я даже целое предложение написал. Но вот что - если все проделывать в терминале, то false, а если написать скрипт и запустить его, то true.

Comment: Но как тогда ожидать предсказуемости от таких условий?

Comment: `a = 1` и `b = 1` совсем не обязаны ссылаться на один и тот же объект, это просто оптимизация, которую захотели сделать конкретные разработчики конкретной реализации питона

Comment: @АликсПлисов никакой предсказуемости ожидать не надо. Сравнивайте через `is` только те объекты, которые вы (прямо или опосредованно) создали сами, и `None`, больше ничего. Числа и строки неизменяемые и `==` для них отлично работает, сравнивать их через `is` нет никакого смысла

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Питон оптимизирует занимаемую им память, есть функция `sys.getrefcount(el)`, которая показывает сколько ссылок ссылается на объект (и пользовательских и нужных питону), вот если ссылок много (для '1' их целых 33), то чтобы не создавать в памяти много одинаковых объектов питон создает один и все ссылки указывают на него. Если ссылок мало ('1 1' - их всего две), то питон создаст новые объекты в памяти (для оптимизации еще рано)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте для разнообразия написать `b_1='1 1'; b_2='1 1'` в одну строчку и проверить getrefcount

Comment: И замените скриншот кодом.